# Wolfram Quantum Framework Shows Mixed States as Kets

Tags: quantum-computing

Wolfram Quantum Framework consistently shows the `state["Formula"]` for mixed states, defined via some density matrix, in terms of simply kets! Is it possible to go from this to the standard ket-bra notation for density matrices?

MWE for this behaviour:

```
state1 = QuantumState[{{1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}}, 2, 1]; (*single maximally mixed state*)
state1["Formula"]
```

produces the incorrect output: `1/2 |00\[RightAngleBracket]+1/2 |11\[RightAngleBracket]`

Wolfram Quantum Framework may be installed with

```
PacletInstall["Wolfram/QuantumFramework"]

Needs["WolframQuantumFramework"]
```

Comment: I added it to the question. It's better for the question to contain all relevant info and links.  Please make sure I copied correctly. I'm not sure the code formatted properly in the comment.

Comment: You can get a list of available properties for state1 using state1["Properties"]. Does state1["MatrixState"] give you the desired form? Incidentally, this is what you get if you remove the semicolon from your first expression.